# Define the expression by the waveform

Tags: voltage, waveform, theory, phase-shift

Could you explain how to define the expression for the dead time \$\theta\$?

[image: Fig.1]

$$f_{1}=\frac{2}{2\pi }\int_{\theta }^{\pi -\theta }{V}_{in}\sin(\omega t)d\omega t
$$

$$f_{1}=-\frac{2{V}_\text{in}}{2\pi }\cos(\omega t)\mid \text{ from }
(\pi -\theta)\text{ to }\theta
$$

$$f_{1}=\frac{2{V}_\text{in}}{2\pi }[\cos(\theta) -\cos(\pi -\theta)]
$$

$$f_{1}=\frac{2{V}_\text{in}}{ \pi } \cos(\theta)
$$

$$=\frac{2{V}_\text{in}}{\pi }\cos\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{d\pi }{2}\right) 
$$

Where $$\theta = \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{d\pi }{2}\right) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand your question correctly you want an analytic expression for the waveform. We can do define it piecewise:

$$
\text{V}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space0\le t<\theta\\
\\
\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}&\space\text{if}\space\theta\le t<\theta+\text{d}\pi\\
\\
0&\space\text{if}\space\theta+\text{d}\pi\le t<2\theta+\text{d}\pi
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When this function is periodic we can write:

$$
\text{V}_\text{i}\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
0&\space\text{if}\space0\le\text{mod}\left(t,2\theta+\text{d}\pi\right)<\theta\\
\\
\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}&\space\text{if}\space\theta\le\text{mod}\left(t,2\theta+\text{d}\pi\right)<\theta+\text{d}\pi\\
\\
0&\space\text{if}\space\theta+\text{d}\pi\le\text{mod}\left(t,2\theta+\text{d}\pi\right)<2\theta+\text{d}\pi
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jan Eerland. But I want to understand how the expression Q=(pi/2-d*pi/2) was obtained. Perhaps you can recommend a book with a solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, I found the answer.
$$\theta+d\pi+\theta=\pi
$$

$$2\theta=\pi-d\pi
$$

$$\theta = \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{d\pi }{2}\right)
$$